# How can i get vCard from command line in Ejabberd 16.03

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

Recently i have updated my ejabberd version from 2.1.13 to 16.03. Now i have a problem, How can i get vCard from the Linux command terminal?

We have a module mod_ctlextra for this in previous versions of ejabberd (from 1.x.x to 2.13.x).

I have done many R&D but i get nothing for ejabberd latest version.

If there is any other module for this or the same module is still available for the latest version too, then please tell me.

Comment: Did u tried http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html

Comment: I want vCard fom command like in mod_ctlextra have ejabberdctl eja@host vcard-get joe myjab.net email

Answer (score 0):

From ejabberdctl command line utility I can see

```
get_vcard user host name 
    Get content from a vCard field

get_vcard2 user host name subname 
    Get content from a vCard field

get_vcard2_multi user host name subname 
    Get multiple contents from a vCard field
```

But you need to have `mod_admin_extra` module enabled in your configuration file.